# How would I indicate that a function takes any iterable except a dictionary?

Tags: python, function, type-hinting

I have a function that will accept an `Iterable[int]`, but I don't want dictionaries to be accepted. I have another method to handle it. How do I indicate that in the type hint?

`def unpack(iterable_to_unpack : Iterable[int]):`

Would `sequence` be more appropriate?

`def unpack(sequence_to_unpack : Sequence[int]):`

From the [definition](https://docs.python.org/3.7/glossary.html#term-iterable) of iterable, it would seem like it.

> An object capable of returning its members one at a time. Examples of
>   iterables include all sequence types (such as list, str, and tuple)
>   and some **non-sequence** types like dict, file objects..

Comment: You’ll have to check the type of the argument and, if it’s a dict, raise an error.

Comment: Right, but would `Sequence[int]` be the correct type hint to indicate that it only accepts `List`, `Tuple`, etc, but not dictionary?

Comment: Could you not simply test  whether `Sequence[int]` is the right type by testing it against `List`, `Tuple`, and `dict` ?

Comment: I could, but I think it would be better to test it like so,`if (isinstance(sequence_to_unpack, Mapping)):` but I still need the correct type hint.

Answer (score 0):

Does this help? From the [docs](https://docs.python.org/3/library/typing.html):

```
from typing import List
Vector = List[float]

def scale(scalar: float, vector: Vector) -> Vector:
    return [scalar * num for num in vector]

# typechecks; a list of floats qualifies as a Vector.
new_vector = scale(2.0, [1.0, -4.2, 5.4])
```

Comment: No, what I'm after is I want my method to accept only Sequence types (List, Tuple, etc..) but not dictionaries, so I was wondering what was the correct type hint. Given that `dict` inherits from `Iterable`, I don't think it's the right type.

Answer (score 0):

## Answer 1: No. (stdlib)

There [currently isn't any way to indicate this](https://discuss.python.org/t/type-intersection-and-negation-in-type-annotations/23879) in just the standard library.

The thread got a bit noised by forum regulars getting in a kerfuffle about whether the OP was asking *specifically* for special-casing `str` or for type subtraction more generally (since *in fact* `issubclass(str, Iterable) == True`; what the OP requested, which is `Intersection[str, Not[Iterable]]`, would be incoherent or `Never`…) but the highlights are:

> If the idea of two operators doesn’t make sense, would it be possible to have “type subtraction”

> Subtraction may be what’s really wanted here.

> Type intersection and negation might be useful concepts. **That’s still to be established.** …
> –Paul Moore (CPython core developer)

## Answer 2: Yes, with `beartype`

You see, [`from beartype.vale import IsInstance`](https://beartype.readthedocs.io/en/stable/api_vale/#beartype.vale.IsInstance) supports the Complement operator.

> This means type hints of the form `typing.Annotated[{superclass}, ~IsInstance[{subclass}]` match all instances of a superclass that are not also instances of a subclass.

That makes the subtraction in question as easy as `Annotated[Collection, ~IsInstance[Mapping]]`!

## Answer 3: Nope, not with `basedtyping`

What you *would* use is something like `Intersection[Collection, Not[Mapping]]`, but [`from basedtyping import Intersection`](https://pypi.org/project/basedmypy/) still leaves you without any access to `Not`. Sad!

---

## Addendum 1: PEP 647

When/if the time comes that you're able to type that function, consider if [`TypeGuard`](https://peps.python.org/pep-0647/) has any place in the internal annotations.

## Addendum 2: [ABCs](https://docs.python.org/3/library/collections.abc.html)

Between `Iterable`, `Collection`, `Sequence`, and `Set`, a layman's summary of the differences is basically this:

- `Iterable` might not be finite
- `Collection` is finite (but might not be ordered)
- `Set` is finite and supports subset/superset/equality checking (but might not be ordered)
- `Sequence` is finite and ordered

So (without knowing your full codebase), you should *probably* consider `Collection`, if your function would be undefined on non-finite inputs, and if `set` (which isn't ordered) is a well-defined input type. (If `set` and `frozenset` are *not* allowed, then you absolutely should use `Sequence`.)

`Mapping` is the more general form of `dict`, in a nutshell (it would include a frozen dict type, for example, which I assume your code would also allow?)

```py
def unpack(collection_or_mapping):
    ...
    if not isinstance(obj, Mapping):
        return _unpack_sequence(obj)
    else:
        return _unpack_mapping(obj)
```

A `Set` is just a comparable `Collection`; the `set` and `frozenset` types *specifically* hve the bonus constraint that `not any(a == b for a, b in combinations(set(x), 2))` — but that's *not* actually part of the typing & ABC `Set` definition; you would, if programming correctly, end up with `issubclass(Multiset, collections.abc.Set)`, for example.

## Addendum 3: X-Y Problem?

Instead of overloading your interface with a run-time `isinstance(obj, Mapping)` check, why not just force your caller to clarify their intent? This would also eliminate the need to even *think* about type narrowing within that function going forwards!

```py
def unpack(collection):
    if isinstance(collection, Mapping):
        logging.warning(TypeError("possible mistake: mapping passed into unpack(). was unpack_from_mapping() meant?"))
    for elem in collection:
        ...

def unpack_from_mapping(d):
    for elem, param in d.items():
        ...
```